# copy images from server to client machine in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to windows application and I stuck with an issue.
I have a web application hosted in server and one of the folder in that application is shared .I am developing the windows application for the same and i need to sync the images in this folder to local folder in client machine's folder. that's why i made it shared in server. So how can i copy these files from server to client.

network path '\server-name\c$\inatallfolder\Install 1\uploadedFiles\uploads'
can it be done using 'File.Copy' .
i found lot of answers in web and stackoverflow itself. Please advise better solution..
thanks and regards,
Sivajith

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i unterstand you correctly. Why can't you copy from a network share?

You could download the files with a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20WebClient):

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    data = client.DownloadData("http://localhost/images/w/abc.jpg");
}
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\client\abc.jpg", data);
```